# SQL Join Query view not working in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am using 3 tables(property,property_rooms,property_images). I have a sql query and need to implement it in Yii action and view.

```
SELECT * FROM property JOIN property_rooms ON property.property_id = property_rooms.property_id JOIN property_images ON property.property_id = property_images.property_id
```

In controller/action i have used the following code:

```
$sql ='SELECT * FROM property JOIN property_rooms ON property.property_id = property_rooms.property_id JOIN property_images ON property.property_id = property_images.property_id';
$properties = property::findBySql($sql)->all();          
return $this->render('index',['properties'=>$properties]);
```

In View file, I have used:

```
<?php foreach ($properties as $property): ?>
    <?= $property->property_id ?>
    <?= $property->price?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The values for the first table is displaying but to access & diplay the values of the other tables.

Comment: remove last `,` from here: `return $this->render('index',['properties'=>$properties,]);`

Comment: first check  `$properties` contains data.

Comment: `price` column must be in `property` table

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using

```
$properties = property::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

`$properties` will contain property models.

You can define relations (such as propertyRooms) and access to them using

```
<?php foreach ($properties as $property): ?>
    <?= $property->property_id ?>
    <?= $property->price?>
    <?php foreach($property->propertyRooms as $pr) : ?>
           <?php /* ... */ ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

For example, propertyRooms property can be defined inside property model as:

```
public function getPropertyRooms() { return $this->hasMany(PropertyRoom::className(), ['property_id' => 'property_id']); }
```

Finally, I'll use ActiveDataProvider methods to get properties data:

```
$properties = property::find()->with('propertyRooms')->all();
```

So you will get all properties data in a single step.